# PHP - Loop cURL with increase id of URL

Tags: php, api, loops, curl

with the following code a name with an ID (each name in the gnd can be addressed by an ID) is received via the GND interface. This works.

Now i want to get many names at the same time with a cURL loop. The ID of the URL must always be increased by one and the cURL request must loop. How can I do this?

With this Code i receive for example names from the GND database

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$User_Agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

$url = "http://hub.culturegraph.org/entityfacts/118600001";      

$request_headers = [];
$request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'charset=utf-8';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, identity';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3';            

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $User_Agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result, true);
if ($code == 200) {
$data = json_decode($result, true);
echo 'Erfolg';
} else {
$error = $data['Error'];
echo 'Beim anfordern der GND-Daten ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: Fehlercode ' . $error;
echo ' <a href="PHP_skript_login.php">Zurueck</a><br />';
}
var_dump($data['preferredName']);
```

Result for URL with ID 118600001 = Gerhardt von Reutern

But how must the code be adapted, so that also the names of the URL's 118600002, 118600003 and so on are output? So as often as it is specified. Be it 100 or 1000 times.

Comment: you create 10 curl handles and only close 1 of them. that's a resource leak and waste of cpu and ram. you can actually keep re-using the same curl handle and just change CURLOPT_URL~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your $url variable to something like $base_url which is the url without the ID

```
$base_url = "http://hub.culturegraph.org/entityfacts/";
```

Then in your for loop you do:

```
$ch = curl_init($base_url . (118600001 + $i));
```

this rule can be removed, this is not necessary:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

You should also handle the response inside the for loop, else you will only see the last person's name, after an incredibly long load time.

Comment: Thanks that works. Do you have any idea how to ingorate empty ID's to avoid error messages? Or can you skip empty ID's?

Comment: You check on the error yourself, just don't throw an error.